# Binary Search Tree Inorder Traversal Python giving recursion Error

Tags: python, recursion, binary-tree

I am trying to implement Binary Tree, I think the tree implementation is working fine as I am able to find my elements using if 8 in tree.  But I when I am trying to perform inOrder Traversal I am running into Recursion Error.

`class BinaryNode:
        def init(self,value):
            self.value = value
            self.left = None
            self.right = None`

```
class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def add(self, value):
        if self.root == None:
            self.root = BinaryNode(value)
        else:

            current = self.root

            while 1:

                if value <= current.value:

                    if current.left:
                        current = current.left
                    else:
                        current.left = BinaryNode(value)
                        break     

                elif value > current.value:

                    if current.right:
                        current = current.right
                    else:
                        current.right = BinaryNode(value)
                        break      

                else:
                    break 


    def __contains__(self, target):
        node = self.root
        while node is not None:
            if node is not None:
                if target < node.value:
                    node = node.left
                elif target > node.value:
                    node = node.right
                else:
                    return True
        return False


    def inorder(self,node):
        node = self.root   

        if node is not None:          
            self.inorder(node.left)
            print (node.value)
            self.inorder(node.right)
</code>
```

```
tree = BinaryTree()
arr = [8,3,1,6]
for i in arr:
    tree.add(i)

print (tree.root.value)
print ('Inorder Traversal')
tree.inorder(tree.root)
```

Error I am getting is "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded" :(  I am trying to check that node is not none before the call, not sure where I am going wrong

Comment: `inorder()` is setting `node` to `self.root` *every single time*, so it never makes any progress.

Comment: good catch, thanks!!! It set the infinite loop